# php module does not compile. Does not recognize "static function_entry"

Tags: php, module, compilation

I have recently recompiled my php and suddenly old code (together with examples from the internet) stopped compiling.

[This](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/) exact example does not compile.

Snippet of the problematic code:

```
static function_entry hello_functions[] = {
  {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

This is the error:

```
/home/user/php_module/test_module/hello.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘hello_functions’
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Solution**:
It's the difference for new php 5.4
Found the answer [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60016)

Had to replace the `function_entry` with static `zend_function_entry`

Works now.