# Compile a third-party DLL to use in PHP

Tags: php, dll, wampserver

I am trying to compile a third party library into a `dll` to use in `PHP5.6.31`. By following the php build directions [here](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild), and the dll's [reference guide](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) (select *'Using lpsolve from PHP'* from the index and scroll down to the compile section). This is what i did.

1. Downloaded the PHP source `php-5.6.31-src.zip` from [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/).
2. Downloaded the binary tools `php-sdk-binary-tools-20110915.zip` from [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/).
3. Downloaded the php libraries `deps-5.6-vc11-x86.7z` from [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/php-sdk/).
4. Set up the build directory and extracted both the source files and the deps to this directory `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\`.
5. Downloaded `lp_solve_5.5.2.5_dev_win32.zip`[here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.5/) and extracted them to `C:\lp_solve_5.5`.
6. Downloaded `lp_solve_5.5.2.5_PHP_source.tar.gz` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.5/) and extracted it, then from the extracted files copied this folder `lp_solve_5.5\extra\PHP` to `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.31-src\ext\lp_solve_5.5`.
7. Opened `VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt` that came with Visual Studio 2012.
8. Ran `C:\php-sdk>bin\phpsdk_setvars.bat` then `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.31-src>buildconf`.
9. Ran `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.31-src>cscript /nologo configure.js --without-xml --without-wddx --without-simplexml --without-dom --without-libxml --disable-zlib --without-sqlite3 --disable-odbc --disable-cgi --enable-cli --without-iconv --enable-phplpsolve55=shared --with-phplpsolve55path="C:\lp_solve_5.5"`.
10. Ran `nmake php_phplpsolve55.dll` which created a dll named `php_phplpsolve55` in this directory `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.31-src\Release_TS`.
11. I then copied `php_phplpsolve55` to my wampserver php extensions folder `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext`.
12. Added this line to my `php.ini` file `extension=php_phplpsolve55.dll`.

Then I restarted Wampserver, but the `php_lpsolve55` extension does not show up in the loaded extensions. I checked the php_error log and this is the error.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_phplpsolve55.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Are there any other ways to troubleshoot this other than the php_error log?
From other posts I read maybe this is a compiler compatibility issue?

Here is my WampServer version.

> WampServer version 3.1.0 - 32bit
>   Apache version: 2.4.27
>   PHP version: 5.6.31

And here are a few properties from `phpinfo()`

> Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
>   PHP Extension Build: API20131226,TS,VC11
>   Thread Safety: enabled

Note: I changed line 5 of `C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc11\x86\php-5.6.31-src\ext\lp_solve_5.5\PHPmod.c` to `static zend_function_entry php_phplpsolve55_functions[] = {` I got this from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688452/php-module-does-not-compile-does-not-recognize-static-function-entry#11632283).

Comment: is the  lpsolve55.dll in a directory that is in the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Thanks @smith adding the `C:\lp_solve_5.5` to the PATH variable got it working.

Comment: FYI: All i did was a little googling and read this: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/PHP.htm